# Issue with laravel composer

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, composer-php

(don,t get angry with that)why we use composer i searched in google it says it is used for the dependencies of laravel, but why we create project in composer?cant we create it in simply in xampp/htdocs/laravel/... there as in past they does in codeigniter?explain it simply and clearly, what is the purpose of using the artisan commands, like php artisan serve that create a host address like localhost:8000 cant we go there in browser simply like localhost/laravelproject?and does composer works offline,without internet access,i mean entering those commands in cmd prompt?simply my concept is not clear with using composer with laravel, clear my concept...thanks

Comment: please visit google.com

Answer (score 0):

As google said, composer is always for dependencies, not just laravel but in any other framework or libraries, composer is used to automatically download dependencies needed for code to work.

Laravel is based on some packages that are some kind of third-party packages. When you create a project in codeigniter you copy all files needed for project. You can do this in laravel too, but you should have all files that are needed. Now you can download all files manually or just set those files and libraries in a file named composer and let composer do that for you. And even if there are dependencies for libraries that you mention for composer, composer detects them and downloads them too.

When you create laravel project with composer, you can save all files and use them for another project (as I did), and not to use composer again.

Artisan commands are just here to help you. Many of commands that are supported by artisan, are possible to be done by your hand, but artisan is here to help you.

Of course you can use xamp or wamp to host your laravel project, here serve command is another option to serve your project. You do not have to use it (as I never do).

Composer does not have dependencies and it just detects dependencies and downloads them.

Hope that helps.

Comment: so its not necessary to create project with composer?i mean i want to make a simple index page or just want to echo a sentence just for example i dont need create-project for that right?because it downloads a whole copy of laravel, m i right?then i can create project folder manually inside ,c/xampp/htdocs/laravel/etc...?

Comment: When you want to crate a project using codeigniter you use codeigniter files (including application directory and system directory). In laravel you should do this too. If you have laravel files (including app directory and vendor directory (that has laravel directory and some others inside) and bootstrap directory), then you don't have to use composer to create project, you should just create controller, action, view, model and routes.

Comment: But if you do not have some of these files (for example vendor directory and laravel directory inside vendor directory), then you do not have enough files for a laravel project. So you have to download these files using composer. Composer will download these files including (vendor folder and some vendor directory like laravel for you). When composer did the job you have all files needed for a laravel project. Now you can create your project. And you can keep these files for your next projects so you don't have to use composer again.